# Update fields in rpt from stored procedure

Tags: crystal-reports

My `.rpt` file gets fields `(field1, field2, ... ,fieldn)` from a stored procedure.

I have since added 2 field to the stored procedure `(field1_new, field2_new)`.

How can I update the old fields `(field1->field1_new, field2->field2_new)` in the `.rpt` file?

Here is a snippet of my project. As you can see in the Group #1 Name, "siteid" from GetCRFData stored procedure is used. I want to change that "siteid" with "siteid_new". I have already clicked "Verify database" and I can see "siteid_new" in Database fields.

[image: snippet]

Before and after @4444 proposition (I just changed site but everything is lost now):

**Before**
[image: before]

---

**After**
[image: after]

Comment: you don't need to update old fields i guess just grab new fields from Field Explorer to your report which will show all of the fields

Comment: @VickyS Can you show me the way or where to look for?

Comment: how are you creating the report through Code Base or Design time

Comment: Design, the report is ready I just want to change these 2 fields

Comment: I always use datasets and xsd files, so i am not sure if it will work for you, but you may try to open the "field explorer", right click the "database fields" and then use the option "verify database". Does this option show up for you?

Answer (score 0):

Open your `.rpt` in the Crystal Reports editor. Then go to Database -> Verify Database.

This will force the report to refresh and validate the stored procedure, as well as any other tables it might be using at any level. If you've only added new fields, and not removed or replaced any, this should be all you need to do.

If you *have* replaced or removed other fields, you might be prompted to manually map a suitable replacement field from the ones it can find.

Comment: I have done the "Verify Database" step. Now I can see my new fields. But my problem is how I can replace the old ones. Please check my edited post

Comment: @aggelos You'll need to manually change things like Groups or Subreports to use the new fields. Right click the group's name and pick Change Group to get here: https://pradeep1210.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/crystalreportschangegroupoptionsdialog5b65d1.jpg

Comment: well I did that, I changed Group but now the report show only the labels and not the values. everywhere.

Comment: @aggelos Can you be more specific? Or better yet, can you post a screenshot demonstrating the new issue?

Comment: @aggelos Do you mean to say the fields are still on the page, but come back blank? Or the fields themselves disappeared from the form?

Comment: Yes they are in the form but they come back blank